# Zipping database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of 1.10gb size in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and when I zipped this database, the file that contains this database will produce the size only 80 Mb.

1. what is the reason for reduce this large amount size?
2. if there any mistake in data allocation in that database that is, static allocation

Comment: For starters the database backup file in sql server is uncompressed in sql2005.  I think that feature was introduced in sql server 2008 ( possibly r2).  Second You should look at the filegrowth setting for your files.  It could be a percentage or in megabytes.  Third, you should look at your recovery model. If its set to simple full, you can shrink the database upon a successful backup. And finally, if you have a really jacked up situation where you tried to configure replication but its broke, then the db will grow out of control.  Too many factors to consider without significant information.

Answer (score 0):

There was no any free technique available for SQL server 2005 backup compression, database administrator could do it by using 3rd party tools.

See this blog: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/davidwimbush/archive/2009/09/24/backup-compression-on-sql-2005.aspx

& 3rd party tool – SQL safe lite, you can find related information @ http://www.idera.com/Products/SQL-toolbox/SQL-safe-lite/
I have not used this software so try it on your own risk.

Also this: http://www.loudsteve.com/2009/01/21/hack-together-backup-compression-in-sql-2005/

Please note that you must Shrink DB before backup and free unused allocated space.